# Find the point on the plane $x+2y+3z = 1$, which is nearest to the point $(-1,0,1)$ by Lagrange’s multiplier method.

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the point on the plane $x+2y+3z = 1$, which is nearest to the point $(-1,0,1)$ by Lagrange’s multiplier method.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$${\min (x+1)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2\\\text{s. t.}\\x+2y+3z-1=0}$$